# Javascript Youtube Data API v3, OAuth2 - Error 403

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-data-api

I'm making a Chrome Extension using Youtube Data V3 Javascript API. My problem is that with my account everything works, but if i give the app to someone else they have an error 403.

The problem is certainly because the popup for giving account access to the app does not show. But the fact is that i'm using the code provided by Youtube to grant access. (THIS ONE: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests)

The token is only used in my options page.

Here is my code :

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Youtube Subsfeed Sorter",
"description": "YSS",
"version": "1.6",

"options_ui":
{
    "page": "options.html"
},

"icons":
{ 
    "128": "LogoYSS.png"
},

"browser_action":
{
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"content_security_policy": "script-src https://*.google.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

"content_scripts": 
[
    {
        "matches": [ "*://www.youtube.com/*" ],
        "css" : ["./css/contentScript.css"],
        "js": ["./lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js", "contentScript.js"],
        "run_at":"document_start",
        "all_frames": true
    }
],

"background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"permissions":
[
    "*://www.youtube.com/*",
    "*://apis.google.com/*",
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
],

"oauth2": 
{
    "client_id":"MyClientId",
    "scopes":
    [ 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
    ]
},

"key": "MyKey"
```

}

Options.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jstree Options text</title>
        <link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="./css/options.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="./css/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jstree.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/auth.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tab-menu" >
            <div id="title">
                <p><img src="LogoYSS.png">Options</img></p>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a id="tab-menu-button" href="#">Onglets</a></li>
                    <li><a id="showing-menu-button" href="#">Affichage</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="Container">
                <div id="ContainerLeft">
                    <form>
                        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Créer un nouvel onglet :</p>
                        <input type="text" id="newtabname" name="newtabename">
                        <button type="button" class="button" id="newtabadd"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                        <p>
                            <button type="button" class="button" id="save"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="button" id="expandall"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="button" id="collapseall"><i class="fa fa-compress fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    <div id="tab"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="channel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="showing-menu">
            <input type="color">Choisir la couleur de fond de la page youtube</input>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A part of my Options.js:

```
   function handleAPILoaded()
    {
        init();
        requestUserSubscriptionList("");
    }

    function requestUserSubscriptionList(nextPageToken) 
    {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.list({
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 50,
                mine: true,
                fields: 'items,nextPageToken',
                order: 'alphabetical',
                pageToken: nextPageToken
            });

            request.execute(function(responseCallBack) 
            {
                nextPageToken = responseCallBack.nextPageToken;

                $.each(responseCallBack.items,function(index,item)
                {
                    if(!/.png/i.test(item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url))
                    {
                        var subNode = {"id" : item.snippet.title , "text": item.snippet.title, "icon" : item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url, "type" : "ChannelSub", "data" : {"channelId" : item.snippet.resourceId.channelId}};
                        $('#channel').jstree().create_node('#',subNode,"last",function(){});
                    }
                });

                if(nextPageToken)
                {
                    requestUserSubscriptionList(nextPageToken);
                }
            });
    }
```

So, if someone can give me some help, i would be very thankful.

**EDIT 1 :**
Here is the error I get when i'm not connected (it's the same error dat my friends had)

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Can you share with us the error logs? In the meantime, check the youtube error response here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've edited my post. I've already check the error response, I know why i get this error, it's because i'm never prompt to grant access of my youtube content to my app.

Comment: Because there are quotas for each API usage by Google.